# WCF, GC and memory management

Tags: .net, wcf, memory-management, serialization

Is it possible to implement "custom" caching in WCF in order to improve memory usage? Or maybe WCF has built in supported for it? Or it is no possible and I don't understand enough how the things works.

For example I have a collection of large objects in server memory cache (~50 items / ~7KB each item after binary serialization). So when it sits in memory there no problem, each object is small and sits in heap. But when I send that collection over WCF, the collection is serialized and it's size about 400KB. Since the byte array is large object now, it sits in Large Object Heap. The exactly same collection is sent over WCF very frequently and this blows the memory by recreating the large array of bytes for each request. Currently we solve it by "communication paging" (splitting the collection to small parts and make several requests to retrieve all items).

Is it possible to pre-serialize the collection and then send over WCF the same array of bytes? I think, if it will be the same instance of bytes array, then even it will sit in LOH, there will be only one instance of array per collection and memory will not blow by recreating large array on each request.

If it's possible, where should I start and what I need to read to implement this?

Comment: If you're sending the same 400K repeatedly to the same client, then you probably should modify the client to cache the data. Do you have evidence that sending this data really is causing memory problems? The object should be removed from the LOH once it's sent.

Comment: I don't really can. There many clients and the collection might change at any time. Client must always have latest version. Of course I trying to use GetIfNewer pattern where possible, but there many different collection types with many clients and requests. So when it all summarized there still memory problems when transferring it. In our case GC not clean memory good enough by itself and using GC.Collect after each request, kills the application.